# What flags and feature gates are set when HPE CP K8S clusters are provisioned?

Tags: hpe-container-platform

I’m trying to demo installing a CSI driver for a customer and decided to go with the AWS EBS driver. The first step is:

```
Enable flag --allow-privileged=true for kube-apiserver
Enable kube-apiserver feature gates --feature-gates=CSINodeInfo=true,CSIDriverRegistry=true,CSIBlockVolume=true,VolumeSnapshotDataSource=true
```

*Source: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/blob/master/docs/README.md*

What flags and feature gates are set when K8S clusters are provisioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out by running the following on the **master** node:

```
$ ps aux | grep apiserver
... kube-apiserver --allow-privileged=true --audit-log-maxage=1 ...
```

Here you can see the flags that are set (in my case I needed `--allow-privileged=true`).

Similarly, you can look for feature-gates:

```
$ ps aux | grep apiserver | grep feature-gates
[empty response]
```

It appears that no feature gates are explicitly enabled on my cluster, so I need to check what is enabled by default.  I can do that by looking [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/).  In the table, I can see that the feature gate **CSINodeInfo** is enabled by default and is GA since 1.17:

[image]

I checked all the required features and they were enabled by default and either Beta or GA on my version of K8S (1.17).